# Deselect all children in partially selected dynatree

Tags: dynatree

I have a hierarchical dynatreee with checboxes. Clicking on a parent checkbox of a partially selected tree FIRST selects all of its children and then toggles between selecting/deselecting all the children. How can I make that FIRST click deselects all the children instead of selecting them?

Thx very much

regards, dejan

Answer (score 1):

In your onSelect function try:

```
onSelect: function(select, node){

    // visit all children of the node and deselect them             
    node.visit(function(node){
        node.select(false);
    });
}
```